# Magento2: How to set new session and clear session in login and logout

Tags: magento2, session

I want to add new session when user logged in also unset this session when user logged out.

When user logged in 
set `$this->customerSession->setRegisterEventId('1');`
after user logged out
Unset `$this->customerSession->unsRegisterEventId();`